# Plotting a contour 3D plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, contour

I entered this code in Matlab:

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(-3:1:3,-3:1:3);
z=sqrt((y.*y)-(x.*x))
contour3(x,y,z)
```

But am getting error for the same. 2D contour plot works out.What's the problem with the given code?

Comment: Ya, it works. But then, how it works with a 2D command?

Comment: The values of z are complex numbers.With the syntax contour(x,y,z) , I am getting a contour plot without specifying the real part.That means, the real part is only taken and imaginary part is omitted,right? But, why its not working with the command contour3(x,y,z)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it full. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: You're welcome :) please accept the answer then. So the problem is marked as solved.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you are introducing complex numbers `contour3` cannot handle.

use either

```
z = abs( sqrt((y.*y)-(x.*x)) )
```

or

```
z = real( sqrt((y.*y)-(x.*x)) )
```

or rethink whether you really want what you are doing.

For the 2D `contour` command it **automatically takes the real part**. You could also do something like this to get both plotted.

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-3:1:3,-3:1:3);

zr = real( sqrt((y.*y)-(x.*x)) )
contour(x,y,zr,'linewidth',1); hold on

zi = imag( sqrt((y.*y)-(x.*x)) )
contour(x,y,zi,'linewidth',3); hold off
```

gives:

[image]

where the bold lines illustrate the imaginary part and the slim ones the real part.